# Terminology for subset of union of $n$ sets where exactly $k$ of them intersect

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given a finite collection of sets $A_{1}, \dotsc, A_{n}$, let $U = \cup_{i} A_{i}$, and define for each $k$ a subset $U_{k}$ of $U$ by

$$U_{k} = \{ p \in U \mid \text{$p$ intersects exactly $k$ of the sets $A_{1}, \dotsc, A_{n}$} \}.$$

It is clear that $U_{1}, \dotsc, U_{n}$ defines a partition of $U$.

I wonder if these subsets have a generally accepted name and are of some importance in set theory.

Also, do they appear in other areas of mathematics, like measure theory, probability, combinatorics?